# Continue Coding/Development during Build is building Angular 2+

Tags: node.js, angular

I came to ask, assume I initialized build using (**ng build environment=X** ),
Can i continue my work as the build is taking place on the other hand on same project?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can continue coding. I did a test when I ran ng build and it was building then I broked one of my files, it still compiled correctly anyway. (Angular 9)

Comment: It seems Angular does build process from its cache?